# Renaming Admin Folder in Opencart

Tags: opencart

I'm new to OpenCart. While I understand the security benefits of renaming the admin folder, and renaming all instances of 'admin' in the config file, my question is: If, for example, I install a payment extension that comes with its own admin and catalog folder to be merged, do I *also* rename the extension’s admin folder to reflect the new change?

The `.htaccess` file isn't an option for now as my IP address isn't static.

Comment: your extension is ocmod or vqmod ?

Answer (score 5):

Steps to Change OpenCart Admin Dashboard URL & Folder

1. Log into your hosting account cPanel, or FTP
2. Navigate to the folder containing the `admin` folder. It is usually the `public_html` or `/var/www/html` folders.
3. Right click on the `admin` folder and choose the “rename” option from the dropdown
4. Enter the new folder name for the `admin` folder. Use an uncommon name which is hard to guess and completely unrelated to your business.  (E.g., `STA22R1`, `ROCKETSCIENCE74851`)
5. Now, edit the `/admin/config.php` and replace *all* instances of the word ‘admin’ with the new folder name you chose in the above step.

   ```
    // HTTP 

    define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://test.domain.com/opencart/**admin**/'); 

    define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://test.domain.com/opencart/');  

    // HTTPS 

    define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://test.domain.com/opencart/**admin**/'); 

    define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://test.domain.com/opencart/'); 

    //DIR 

    define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/userna5/public_html/opencart/**admin**/'); 

    define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/userna5/public_html/opencart/system/'); 

    define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/userna5/public_html/opencart/system/database/'); 

    define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/userna5/public_html/opencart/**admin**/language/');

    define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/userna5/public_html/opencart/**admin**/view/template/'); 

    define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/userna5/public_html/opencart/system/config/'); 

    define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/userna5/public_html/opencart/image/'); 

    define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/userna5/public_html/opencart/system/cache/'); 

    define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/userna5/public_html/opencart/download/'); 

    define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/userna5/public_html/opencart/system/logs/'); 

    define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/userna5/public_html/opencart/catalog/');  


    // DB

    define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');

    define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');

    define('DB_USERNAME', 'username_example');

    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');

    define('DB_DATABASE', 'username_example');

    define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
   ```
6. If you are using vQmod, you will have to update the `pathReplaces.php` file, located in the `/vqmod` directory. The code to rename the ‘admin’ folder should already be there. It will be similar to the code shown below:

   ```
   $replaces[] = array('~^admin\b~', 'backend');
   ```
7. Replace the word `backend` with the new folder name you chose in the above steps.

Answer (score 1):

If you rename the admin folder, then the other extension you are trying to install will not work because it is looking for the admin folder, and that folder doesn't exists in the directory, so it will give you an error like “No `/admin` directory exists”.

But if you renamed the extension folder to match your OpenCart admin folder, then it may depend if your extension has an `install.xml`. If it does, then it will not work properly. But if there is no `install.xml`, then it will work properly.